# C programming Im trying to switch content from 2 txt files

Tags: c, file, input, output

I'm trying to switch the content of 2 txt files, they just have lines with characters.

I tried to do this, the program compiles but doesn't modify anything in the text files. Is there another way to do this?

```
FILE *f, *p;
char linha[TAM], linha2[TAM];

f =fopen("texto.txt", "r");

if(f==NULL)
{
    printf("Erro ao abrir ficheiro");
    fclose(f);
    return;
}

p =fopen("texto2.txt", "r");

if(p==NULL)
{
    printf("Erro ao abrir ficheiro");
    fclose(p);
    return;
}


while( fgets(linha,TAM,f) != NULL || fgets(linha2,TAM,p) != NULL )
{
    if(strcmp(linha, "") != 0)
    {
        fprintf(p, "%s", linha);
    }

    if(strcmp(linha2, "") != 0)
    {
        fprintf(f, "%s", linha2);
    }
}

fclose(f);
fclose(p);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: the txt files are already created, I tried to switch to "w" to check and that action emptied the txt files

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by @PaulStelian direct swapping is problematic. Take swapping two variables as an analogy: for it to work, you must store the data of one variable somewhere temporarily. (Or use XOR-swapping, which is sweet, but hacky and works on binary data.)

Your best bet is probably to duplicate one file and then do swapping like

```
duplicateFile = copy(file1);
file1 = file2;
file2 = duplicateFile;
```

---

For `fopen`, use the `r+` option to open a file for both reading and writing. `r` merely opens it for reading.

From `man fopen`:

> `r`   Open text file for reading.  The stream  is  positioned  at 
>   the
>                 beginning of the file.
>
> `r+`     Open  for  reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the
>                 beginning of the file.

Comment: It will still be troublesome; having both reads and writes in a file where records have variable size (and text files generally have variable-sized lines) is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: The original goal needs to use the "r+" option AND to be completely rewritten in every other way. Not seeking back to the beginning of the line being replaced? Reading arbitrary length blocks?

Comment: Swapping two files should happen using fixed sized blocks, binary mode, and if the files don't have the same size the only correct swaps are not portable (requiring OS specific instructions -- truncate; but in that case you can simply use rename). http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Renaming-Files.html

Comment: Well, then I guess the best option is like using a temporary txt file to save one of them first, right?

Comment: Oh I see. Since the beginning I saw that this would have some troubles

Comment: @WalterPalma That's a good option actually, combined with the "w" option. It can be pretty portable, but it doesn't prevent you from losing the content of one of the files in the more complex situations. But for a beginner it's the better option.

Comment: @user3121023 Wasn't aware that `rename` was in the C standard library, thought it was a POSIX or GNU extension.

Comment: I agree that simultaneous reading and writing are problematic, but swapping through a temporary? This sounds so inefficient for the general case. For small files, OK, it's simple and all, but for larger files I would really refrain from doing that.

Comment: Well, thank you all. It was my first question and I felt that this is a very good community, thanks!

Comment: @cadaniluk I doubt .txt files can be that large. Also the question's wording was actually showing that the OP is a beginner, so a simple answer was warranted.

Comment: @PaulStelian Looked it up, C99 has `rename`, see `man 2 rename`. POSIX extends this to other file types than regular ones, see `man 3 rename`.